# Use $ in lstlisting

Tags: listings, characters

I need to create some jQuery-Listings but when I try to do so

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4, .4, .4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
        keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
        ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
        identifierstyle=\color{black},
        sensitive=false,
        comment=[l]{//},
        morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
        commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
        morestring=[b]',
        morestring=[b]"}

\lstset{
        language=JavaScript,
        backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        extendedchars=true,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        showspaces=false,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        numbersep=9pt,
        tabsize=2,
        breaklines=true,
        showtabs=false,
        frame=leftline,
        caption=\lstname}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=Beispiel mit JavaScript Bibliothek (jQuery)]
\$("p").elements.each(function() {
        \$(this).html = "Element erkannt";
});
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The `$` doesn't get displayed. If I try to escape it normally using `\$("#test")`, it ends up looking like **`\ ("test")`**. The `$` is still omitted and the backslash is displayed.

How can I get the `$` to work in a lstlisting?

Comment: we need more informations about your font setting

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem. Upon suitable completion your code snippet doesn't show the bahaviour mentioned.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NBbvwjhC - Working example

Comment: @ApoY2k For the next time please edit your question to add the MWE. For me it works fine. Also without the backslash.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was a little too much text to add to the question. Could it have something to do with the packages I'm using?!

Comment: The above code displays the `$`s correctly for me. I agree with Herbert that is is most likely a font issue.

Comment: I use lstlisting as well, and I didn't need to escape it...

Comment: The MWE works fine for me. I've had problems with symbols not showing up in listings before and I solved them by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the beginning of my preamble...

Comment: Compile your document with pdflatex and put the log file and the resulting pdf somewhere on the net for inspection.

Comment: As stated before, this works for other people and me. Please update your TeX installation to the latest version and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer is based on a previous answer of mine from another problem : [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18532/listing-language-for-screen-session/18559#18559))

The solution is to use the `literate` option within the `lsset` command. I modified your code (note that you need only enter `$` and not `\$` in the actual code listing. For visual purposes, I included a coloring for the $ but you may change it to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4, .4, .4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
        keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
        ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
        identifierstyle=\color{black},
        sensitive=false,
        comment=[l]{//},
        morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
        commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
        morestring=[b]',
        morestring=[b]"}

\lstset{
        language=JavaScript,
        backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        extendedchars=true,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        showspaces=false,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
        numbersep=9pt,
        tabsize=2,
        breaklines=true,
        showtabs=false,
        frame=leftline,
        caption=\lstname,
        literate={\$}{{\textcolor{blue}{\$}}}1
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=Beispiel mit JavaScript Bibliothek (jQuery)]
$("p").elements.each(function() {
        $(this).html = "Element erkannt";
});
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry, it looks like my answer does not address the actual problem here)

You can add `mathescape=false` to your `\lstset{...}` and use non-escaped `$` signs in your listing.

If you need both the mathescape functionality and to display `$` characters you can change the `escapechar`.