# How to customize \lstset for each \lstinputlisting environment in my document?

Tags: listings, code, matlab-prettifier

These are the settings of my overleaf project (they were given to me by my Professor):

```
% Listings and related stuff

\usepackage[hyper]{listings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% pacchetto caricato da G.Donnarumma
\usepackage{listingsutf8} % to write accented words in listing environment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listato}
\newcommand{\lstInCaption}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize]|#1|}

% MATLAB as default 
\lstset{%
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
    float=hbp,%
    language=Matlab,%
    style=Matlab-editor,   %richiede il pacchetto matlab-prettifier (inserito da G.Donnarumma)
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, %font size/family/etc.for source \small
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},%
    stringstyle=\color{colString},%
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},%
    columns=[l]fixed,% flexible,%
    keepspaces=false,%        sposta la linea di separazione delle sezioni 
    %tabsize=2,%
    frame=single,% single,lines, none
    rulecolor= \color{boxgray},%specify the color of  the frame-box 
    extendedchars=true,%
    showspaces=false,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    escapechar         = ",      %inserito da G.Donnarumma
    mlshowsectionrules = true,   %inserito da G.Donnarumma
    numbers=left,% left, none    %visualizza num. identificat. linea codice
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
    breaklines=true,     %automatic line-breaking
    lineskip=-2pt,       %
    backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray}, %
    breakautoindent=true,       %
    numberbychapter=true,       %
    captionpos=false,    %position of caption (t/b)
    belowcaptionskip=0.2\baselineskip%\medskipamount%
}
\lstset{%
   morekeywords={cell,interp1,interp3,interpn,fnplt,fneval%
      ,odeset,ode113,ode15s,ode23s,ode23t,ode23tb,ode45,cell2mat,convangvel,convvel,convang,convforce,convlength,deg2rad,atmoscoesa,atmosisa,atmosnonstd,%
      datcomimport,importdata,fieldnames,assignin%
      ,fnval,csaps,fmincon%
      ,classdef,properties,methods%
   }
}
\lstset{%
   emph={myfun,myfunction2x1,f_prandtl_a_b,%
      DSVAircraft,myAC,costLongEquilibriumStaticStickFixed,myNonLinearConstraint,dummyNonLinearConstraint,%
      eqLongDynamicStickFixed,calc_CD0_k_Tmax,MassStickFree,cla,eps,},%
   emphstyle={%
      \color{red!80!black}%
         \ttfamily\bfseries%
   }
}

\lstset{% "interp1" and "ode45" were in this list 
    emph=[1]{pi,norm,sin,cos,disp,cd,set,get,gca,gradient,length,tan,gamma,sqrt,diag,acos,atan,asin,imag,real,subplot,sound,zeros,interp2,meshgrid,input,sprintf,xlabel,ylabel,plot,print, legend,grid,figure,hold},emphstyle=[1]\color{black}, %some words to emphasise
}


% DATCOM
\lstdefinelanguage{Datcom}{%
    emph={%
        \$FLTCON,\$OPTINS,\$SYNTHS,\$BODY,%
        \$WGPLNF,\$HTPLNF,\$VTPLNF,\$SYMFLP,\$ASYMFLP,%
        \$},%
    emphstyle={%
          \color{red!80!black}%
            \ttfamily\bfseries%
        },%
    morekeywords={%
        WT,\$,NMACH,MACH,NALT,ALT,NALPHA,ALSCHD,%
        SREF,CBARR,BLREF,%
        XCG,XW,ZW,ALIW,XH,ZH,ALIH,XV,ZV,VERTUP,%
        NX,X,R,%
        CHRDTP,SSPNE,SSPN,CHRDR,SAVSI,CHSTAT,%
        TWISTA,SSPNDD,DHDADI,DHDADO,TYPE,%
        NACA,%
        CASEID,%
        DAMP,DIM,DERIV,TRIM,PART,SAVE,NEXT,CASE%
        WT,LOOP,NMACH,MACH,VINF,NALPHA,ALSCHD,RNNUB,NALT,%
            ALT,PINF,TINF,HYPERS,STMACH,TSMACH,TR,GAMMA,%
        SREF,CBARR,BLREF,ROUGFC,XCG,ZCG,XW,ZW,ALIW,XH,ZH,ALIH,XV,XVF,ZV,ZVF,SCALE,%
        VERTUP,HINAX,NX,X,S,P,R,ZU,ZL,BNOSE,BTAIL,BLN,BLA,DS,%
        ITYPE,METHOD,CHRDR,CHRDBP,CHRDTP,SSPN,SSPNE,SSPNOP,SAVSI,SAVSO,CHSTAT,%
        TWISTA,SSPNDD,DHDADI,DHDADO,TYPE,TOVC,DELTAY,XOVC,CLI,ALPHAI,CLALPA,CLMAX,CMO,%
        LERI,LERO,CAMBER,TOVCO,XOVCO,CMOT,CLMAXL,CLAMO,TCEFF,KSHARP,SLOPE,ARCL,%
        XAC,DWASH,YCM,CLD,TYPEIN,NPTS,XCORD,YUPPER,YLOWER,MEAN,THICK,NGH,%
        GRDHT,FTYPE,NDELTA,DELTA,PHETE,PHETEP,CHRDFI,CHRDFO,SPANFI,SPANFO,%
        CPRMEI,CPRMEO,CAPINS,CAPOUT,DOSDEF,DOBCIN,DOBCOT,SCLD,SCMD,%
        CB,TC,NTYPE,JETFLP,CMU,DELJET,EFFJET,STYPE,NDELTA,DELTAL,DELTAR,%
        SPANFI,SPANFO,PHETE,CHRDFI,CHRDFO,DELTAD,DELTAS,XSOC,XSPRME,%
        HSOC,AIETLP,NENGSP,THSTCP,PHALOC,PHVLOC,PRPRAD,ENGFCT,%
        BWAPR3,BWAPR6,BWAPR9,NOPBPE,BAPR75,YP,CROT,%
        AIETLJ,AMBSTP,AMBTMP,JEALOC,JEANGL,JELLOC,JERAD,JESTMP,%
        JETOTP,JEVELO,JEVLOC,JIALOC,JINLTA,NENGSJ,THSTCJ%
    },
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstdefinelanguage{DatcomOutput}{%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyInputForMatlab}{%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyNoSpecificLanguage}{%
    emph={},%
    emph={[2]},%
    emph={[3]},%
    emph={[4]}%
}

\lstloadlanguages{Matlab,Datcom,DatcomOutput,MyInputForMatlab,MyNoSpecificLanguage}

% see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18532/listing-language-for-screen-session
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLine}
    {\lstset{%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~,% use this for output
        morekeywords={ls,pwd,cp,mv},
        identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
        keywordstyle=\color{red!60!black}\bfseries,% \color{colKeys},%\fontseries{b}\selectfont, %
        stringstyle=\color{colString}, %
        literate={\$}{{\textcolor{blue}{\$}}}1}% prompt symbol
    }
    {}
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLineOutput}
    {\lstset{%
        language=MyNoSpecificLanguage,%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,%
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        lineskip=-1pt,%
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~% use this for output
        }
    }
    {}
\lstnewenvironment{myCommandLineOutputSmaller}
    {\lstset{%
        language=MyNoSpecificLanguage,%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
        backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray},% \color{hellgelb}, %
        lineskip=-1pt,%
        frame=none,%
        columns=[l]fixed,%flexible, %
        prebreak=\makebox[1.4ex][r]{\color{blue}\raisebox{-0.9ex}[0ex][0ex]{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}},
        keepspaces=true,%
        escapechar=~% use this for output
        }
    }
    {}
```

Can you show me ho to use the environment `\lstinputlisting[]{code.m}` if I want to change only some settings for different listings in my document (for example, I want to specify if the language is Matlab or DATCOM, or I want to choose if to show or not the numbers on the side of the code and so on.)?

So, I want to know how to recall all the settings (for example the ones about matlab) and then how to customize some of them time by time for different uses of the `\lstinputlisting[]{code.m}` environment.

I've tried to write something like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,style=Matlab-editor,captionpos=b,numbers=none,caption=title}.,label=test,firstline=30,lastline=56]{code.m}
```

But I obtain that the style is different from this one (the general command that I used previously):

```
\lstinputlisting[caption=title,label=test,firstline=30,lastline=56]{code.m}
```

My goal is only to delete the numbers and to insert the caption but I want to mantain the style defined here:

```
\lstset{%
   inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
   float=hbp,%
   language=Matlab,%
   style=Matlab-editor,   %richiede il pacchetto matlab-prettifier (inserito da G.Donnarumma)
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, %font size/family/etc.for source \small
   identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
   keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},%
   stringstyle=\color{colString},%
   commentstyle=\color{colComments},%
   columns=[l]fixed,% flexible,%
   keepspaces=false,%        sposta la linea di separazione delle sezioni 
   %tabsize=2,%
   frame=single,% single,lines, none
   rulecolor= \color{boxgray},%specify the color of  the frame-box 
   extendedchars=true,%
   showspaces=false,%
   showstringspaces=false,%
   escapechar         = ",      %inserito da G.Donnarumma
   mlshowsectionrules = true,   %inserito da G.Donnarumma
   numbers=left,% left, none    %visualizza num. identificat. linea codice
   numberstyle=\tiny,%
   breaklines=true,     %automatic line-breaking
   lineskip=-2pt,       %
   backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgray}, %
   breakautoindent=true,       %
   numberbychapter=true,       %
   captionpos=false,    %position of caption (t/b)
   belowcaptionskip=0.2\baselineskip%\medskipamount%
}
```